# What is the best practice for schema free models in Java POJO?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, jackson, nosql

I'm using Java POJOs to handle models with a schema free database like ElasticSearch; by serializing them as JSON with Jackson. Several fields in the model are "fixed", shared for every object in database.

However, some objects may have different fields, as in every schema-free architecture. What is the best practice to handle models like this?

At the moment, I'm using simple multi-dimensional HashMap(s) in the model itself, but it's tricky and maybe not the best solution (in particular, one can't handle multi-level fields). Is there a best practice for situations like this one?

Comment: I don't know if it is best practice, but we handle this by providing accessor methods for the common, always-available properties (`getCommonProperty()`). The optional attributes are either accessed with simple `getProperty(String)` methods or, if some objects/classes are used often, we subclass our common class and add the typed accessors. So in general, your approach seems like a reasonable way to go.

Comment: The problem is that our software is huge, and we provide several extensions and user-written plug-ins in Jython/Groovy/etc. that can access to the same model, but may need to write custom fields to it. By using subclasses, the fields are "fixed" anyway to a set of possibile subclasses.

Comment: I agree that the subclasses are only a good idea if and when you reuse the same model - at least in parts - in several places. But, as you also mention, I don't know the most elegant way to deal with the dynamic model except for the generic `getProperty(String key)`. I will follow this question and discussion, though, maybe someone else presents a nicer idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the use of polymorphic types, where base class can define common set of properties, sub-classes additional ones. Depending on your needs, you may also need to enable polymorphic handling; that is, depending on whether you know the intended type from context (no need for type info), or if not (that is, it's stored in JSON document; if so, polymorphic handling needed).

However: a simpler and more dynamic (but less type-safe) approach may be to use "dyna-beans" approach, explained for example here:

http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html

so that you define a set of named, fully-typed core properties; and the rest can be included as needed. Types for such extra properties will need to be "natural" types (Strings, Numbers, Booleans, Map, List), but you can use Jackson to further convert back and forth between these and POJOs (using `ObjectMapper.convertValue()`).

Or, if you prefer, dynamic properties can also be specified as `JsonNode`s, in which case you get nicely traversable JSON tree access.